# Phonegap with InAppBrowser plugin to .ipa File

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Using Phonegap 3.3.0

I added the InAppBrowser - everything works on XCode Simulator.

When I zip the whole folder (include www, plugins, platforms, merges), and uploaded it to Build.Phonegap.com - grab the QR Code onto my iPhone. Download the app - the InAppBrowser didn't work..

I changed the Bundle ID in XCode from default "com.phonegap.helloworld" to my own ID. The XCode simulator didn't work.

Ultimately how do I get the .ipa file from XCode reliability for App Store submission.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Phonegap 3.3.0

Very delicately

In Terminal,

```
phonegap create App-Name --name "App-Name"

phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

phonegap build ios
```

With InAppBrowser, it should already be set up for in Config.xml. But you got to add:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```